# Auto adjust panel width based on content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap in order to manage my content. However, I now need my width to be able to use a horizontal scroll.
Here's what it looks like (ps : generated with Razor and foreach so quite easy :) ) :

```
    <div class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-2">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <table class="gridtable table-bordered table-spacing">
    <td class="gridrow">
      <th class="gridcol sidebar">Col 1</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 2</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 3</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 4</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 5 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 6</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 7</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 8</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 9</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 10</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 11</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 12</th>
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-2">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <table class="gridtable table-bordered table-spacing">
    <td class="gridrow">
      <th class="gridcol sidebar">Col 1</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 2</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 3</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 4</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 5</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 6</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 7</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 8</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 9</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 10</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 11</th>
      <th class="gridcol content">Col 12</th>
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here the jsfiddle as an example : https://jsfiddle.net/dwhxuvfn/29/.

My problem is that the content in Col 2, Col 3, etc... can now be bigger than anticipated. The problem then becomes that my columns break to go to a new line, which I don't want. If the content in one of the column is too big, I want all the columns to increase in width and add a horizontal scroll if needed.

PS : yes, I know that it's stupid since the goal is to make it responsive, but that's what the client wants...

Does anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks.

Edit : I have multiple tables, and I need all the columns to be aligned. I edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use float on table cells. This usually breaks the table layout and makes your life a lot harder.
I've made a few minor changes to your jsfiddle and I think it displays the table as you want it to: https://jsfiddle.net/efumgprd/

For table header columns it's a good idea to use `white-space:nowrap` so that they'll have equal heights and they'll force the table to extend without attempting to wrap the text inside.

```
@media only screen {
    .gridtable {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    .gridcol {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's great. The problem in your example is that all the columns don't auto resize.
The reason I wanted that is because I have multiple tables and I need all the columns for all the tables to be aligned. Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dwhxuvfn/29/
In your example, col 6 (and after) is clearly not aligned between both tables. :(

Comment: @FlorianReiss I'm afraid you can't synchronise the column widths of two separate tables by just using CSS, you'll need javascript for that. 
However if you keep both sets of columns inside the same table and interpolate the 'some-content' parts as different sections of the table, you can obtain the result you're aiming for: https://jsfiddle.net/w8crz05s/

Comment: the problem with that approch is that my table is bordered. With you way of doing things, I would have a border everywhere when I only want it on certain tables (not the first one for example).
Using javascript is alright with me. Do you have any examples I could use ?

Comment: It is possible to add borders or other different styles to different <thead> sections. Check out my updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w8crz05s/7
The `border-collapse` property on the gridtable is required for this to work.
As for the javascript approach, it's a much longer discussion: the most basic approach would be to use an element resize detector on the columns with a callback that synchronises all column widths in all tables. There are loads of jQuery tutorials out there that can help you :)